# Getting data grid combobox column value

Tags: c#, wpf, combobox, selectedvalue

I've got the following code and I'm trying to get the selected combobox value:

```
<DataGridTemplateColumn x:Name="StatusCombo"  Header="Change Status">
    <DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
        <DataTemplate>
            <ComboBox x:Name="sslStatusTableCombo" Canvas.Left="307" Canvas.Top="59" 
                      Width="120" SelectedIndex="0" 
                      DropDownClosed="dataTableComboBox_DropDownClosed" SelectedItem="0">
                <ComboBoxItem Content="status1"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="status2"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="status3Approval"/>
                <ComboBoxItem Content="status4"/>
            </ComboBox>
        </DataTemplate>
    </DataGridTemplateColumn.CellTemplate>
</DataGridTemplateColumn>
```

With a `dataTableComboBox_DropDownClosed`. How can I get the current combobox value?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Cast the sender object to ComboBox and then to ComboBoxItem.

```
private void dataTableComboBox_DropDownClosed(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    var SelectedValue = ((ComboBoxItem) ((ComboBox) sender).SelectedValue).Content;
}
```

Your SelectedValue variable will have the selected Item.

Comment: Thank you! Exactly what I was after.